# How do I change which Legend object is displaying this series?

Tags: c#, charts

Data.Visualization.Charting

I have a chart control with 2 ChartAreas. But all the Legend names are being shown in a single Legend object.

I know how to create a second Legend object, BUT how do I associate a series with this second Legend object so that I see Legend entry ONLY in second Legend object?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign which `Legend` contains a `Series` simply be setting the `Series`' `Legend` property:

```
Legend L2 = chart1.Legends.Add("L2"); 
someSeries.Legend = "L2";
```